# SharedPreferences.getInstance() is always returning null

Tags: flutter, dart

Coming from Object Oriented Programming Background, I planned on making a dedicated Settings Class to store certain basic data about the app.

I planned on starting with saving the theme of the application using SharedPreferences and LocalStorage.

However, SharedPreferences.getInstance() always seems to be returning null.

I have tried simply running, running in Debug mode, having a separate async method to load the SharedPreferences and returning a Future which is unwrapped using .then(). I can't seem to figure out why I am always getting null from SharedPreferences.getInstance() in the AppSettings.getInstance() method that I have written.

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:localstorage/localstorage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppSettings {
  // Singleton Instance
  static AppSettings _appSettings;

  // For First Launch Recognition
  bool _initialize;

  // Storage instances for persistent settings storage
  static SharedPreferences _prefs;
  static LocalStorage _dayColors = new LocalStorage('_dayColors');
  static LocalStorage _nightColors = new LocalStorage('_nightColors');

  // App Settings
  bool _nightTheme;

  Color _dayBgColor;
  Color _primaryDayColor;
  Color _secondaryDayColor;
  Color _accentDayColor;

  Color _nightBgColor;
  Color _primaryNightColor;
  Color _secondaryNightColor;
  Color _accentNightColor;

  static AppSettings getInstance() {
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) => _prefs = prefs);
    _appSettings ??= AppSettings._();
    return _appSettings;
  }

  ///
  /// Initialize App Settings
  ///
  AppSettings._() {
    _checkIfFirstLaunch();
    if (_initialize) {
      _loadDefaultSettings();
      _saveSettings();
    } else {
      _loadSettings();
    }
  }

  _checkIfFirstLaunch() {
    try {
      _initialize = _prefs.getBool("_initialize");
    } catch (e) {
      _initialize = true;
    }
  }

  _loadSettings() {
    _nightTheme = _prefs.getBool("_nightTheme");

    _dayColors.ready.then((_) => _loadDayColors());
    _nightColors.ready.then((_) => _loadNightColors());
  }

  _loadDefaultSettings() {
    _nightTheme = false;

    _dayBgColor = Colors.white;
    _primaryDayColor = Colors.blue;
    _secondaryDayColor = Colors.lightBlue;
    _accentDayColor = Colors.blueAccent;

    _nightBgColor = Colors.black54;
    _primaryNightColor = Colors.green;
    _secondaryNightColor = Colors.lightGreen;
    _accentNightColor = Colors.amber;
  }

  _saveSettings() {
    _prefs.setBool("_nightTheme", _nightTheme);

    _dayColors.ready.then((_) => _saveDayColors());
    _nightColors.ready.then((_) => _saveNightColors());
  }
}
```

SharedPreferences.getInstance() should return SharedPreferences singleton instance. It keeps returning null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is async and your callback (`then`) executes after of the return of `getInstance()`. You must change your function to use `await` and get the value of `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` instead use `SharedPreferences.getInstance().then(...)`

Look the documentation: https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/getInstance.html

Implementation of SharedPreferences.getInstance().

```
static Future<SharedPreferences> getInstance() async {
  if (_instance == null) {
    final Map<String, Object> preferencesMap =
        await _getSharedPreferencesMap();
    _instance = SharedPreferences._(preferencesMap);
  }
  return _instance;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Let me try this out, and I'll report back!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked based on Augusto's answer:

```
static Future<AppSettings> getInstance() async {
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _appSettings ??= AppSettings._();
    return _appSettings;
}
```